# ios sqlite not opening with Xcode (but from cli) - ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, ionic-framework

I can run and build my app from the cli (ionic cordova build ios).
When I do the same with Xcode my app starts, but the sqlite database ist not able to open:

```
**OPEN database: mydb.db FAILED, aborting any pending transactions**

**{"code":0,"__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0},"line":26,"column":27,"sourceURL":"ionic://localhost/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js"}**
```

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 0.2.9)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.10.2
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027
```

How can there be any difference?

Comment: Where is the dB in the file system? If it’s in the bundle you’re quite likely to have issues. I.e clone it to Documents or Cache before trying to open.

Comment: I'm not really sure where it is, but because I made no changes to a former version which opened correctly it should be fine, or not?

Comment: if it is drag and dropped in Xcode then surely it is in bundle copy it to document path, I am also using db in the bundle that is readable from there but not writeable.

Comment: it is not drag and dropped, I build it once per cli with "ionic cordova build ios" from my editor and then open Xcode via the .workspace file under platforms/ios and run with the play button

Comment: my database is stored in "Library/LocalDatabase". I cannot put it anywhere else, because on every device which updates the app it'll still be there. I tried to set the iosDatabaseLocation to iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library/LocalDatabase', but it is still OPEN database: mydb.db FAILED, aborting any pending transactions

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the connection between sqlcipher and sqlite:
In a previous version sqlcipher-adapter 0.2.1 worked with sqlite-adapter 3.0.0 without a problem. 
I get it working now with sqlcipher-adapter 0.1.12-rc3 and sqlite-adapter 3.3.0!